# Failed to determine the https port for redirect

Tags: redirect, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, c#-10.0

I am new to ASP.NET and programming too. I am using Visual Studio 2022 v17.5 and ASP.NET Core 6 for building a web application.

I am in the development environment. Initially all was going well but suddenly it starting misbehaving by showing

> Warning: Failed to determine the https port for redirect

The web page loads but doesn't respond to any click and browser reload animation also keeps on revolving.

[image]

I searched the internet but failed to find any fix. Please guide to fix this error and thanks in advance for any solution.

Comment: Have you tried to add `"https_port": 443,` in your appsetting.json?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. The response is "This site can't be reached".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.
Solved by deleting all .vs folder

Comment: Unfortunately, after I had again the same issue later... trying to fix with VS repair

Answer (score 5):

Here is an answer from [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu):

A port must be available for the middleware to redirect an insecure request to HTTPS. If no port is available:

- Redirection to HTTPS doesn't occur.
- The middleware logs the warning    "Failed to determine the https
  port for redirect."

Specify the HTTPS port using any of the following approaches:

- Set HttpsRedirectionOptions.HttpsPort.
- Set the https_port host setting:

  - In host configuration.
  - By setting the ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT environment variable.
  - By adding a top-level entry in appsettings.json:

    `"https_port": 443,`
- Indicate a port with the secure scheme using the ASPNETCORE_URLS
  environment variable. The environment variable configures the server.
  The middleware indirectly discovers the HTTPS port via
  IServerAddressesFeature. This approach doesn't work in reverse proxy
  deployments.
- The ASP.NET Core web templates set an HTTPS URL in
  Properties/launchsettings.json for both Kestrel and IIS Express.
  launchsettings.json is only used on the local machine.
- Configure an HTTPS URL endpoint for a public-facing edge deployment
  of Kestrel server or HTTP.sys server. Only one HTTPS port is used by
  the app. The middleware discovers the port via
  IServerAddressesFeature.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution sir. I got my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75755560/2261090

Comment: I find this answer is much more concise and speaks to how to address the issue outside of development. When running the application in a deployed environment, I was getting this. So the current selected answer does not apply, because you don't have a .vs folder in a deployed environment

Comment: Thank you! Simply setting the ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT environment variable in my docker run command fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Heres something I found when I had the same problem. Set the Application Pool to "Load User Profile" -> TRUE.
This is because IIS passes the HTTP port info in environment variables. It will probably work on your PC as its running in your profile, once IIS hosts it then its a different profile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using version .NET 7 and after installing the SignalR package, I encountered a problem.

The solution for me was to change the package whose last version was for .NET 8 to version 7. I hope it will be useful.